# How to update the attribute of rect after draw rectangle in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

This is my function step

1. when mousedown event happens, I will draw a rectangle with size (mousedown.x,mousedown.y,0,0) in canvas
2. then start mousemove, The size of rectangle will change, following the mouse position
3. when mouseup happens, draw will complete

Now, I can draw rectangle in canvas, but I don't know how to update the size of rectangle when mousemove

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to store the initial `mousedown.x` and `mousedown.y` in a global variable during the `mouseDown` event.

During the `mouseMove` event, you want to check if the current mouse X is bigger than the initial mouse X. If yes, make the width of the rect to be the current X - initial X. Otherwise, you may want to set the Y of the rect to be the current X and the width to be the initial X - current X.

The same can be done for the y.

You want to check if the current mouse Y is bigger than the initial mouse Y. If yes, make the height of the rect to be the current Y - initial Y. Otherwise, you may want to set the Y of the rect to be the current Y and the width to be the initial Y - current Y.

Make sure to clear the canvas or at least the previous drawing on the canvas at the beginning of the `mouseMove` event.

To clear the entire canvas, just make a rect with an x and y at 0 and a width and height the same as the width and height of the canvas. Make sure this rect is using the same color as the background color of the canvas. After this, change the color you are using back to the color that your `rect` should be.

To clear just the previous drawing, you would need to store the x and y of the most recent `mouseMove` event and check at the beginning of the `mouseMove` and create a rect using the same logic that you used to create the rect before. Use the same color as the background color of the canvas. Remember to change back the color to the color your `rect` should be afterwards.

If you are anticipating multiple shapes to be drawn, you can store each shape's x and y, and width and height in an array of objects and then after clearing the canvas using `rect` in the beginning of the `mouseMove` event, you could loop through them and redraw them and then do any further `mouseMove` logic.

Comment: I have a global array to store the position,Now when I  move the mouse, It will appear many rectangle in canvas @Moishe Lipsker

Comment: before each mouseMove event, you will need to clear the canvas or the previous drawing on the canvas

Comment: If I draw second rectangle the first rectangle will be clear too @Moishe Lipsker

Comment: no at the beginning of each `mouseMove` event clear out the previous rect and then change the color that you're drawing with back to the color you'd like to use for your rect

Answer (score 0):

Is there any specific reason for using canvas? SVG would be a better choice for this case. Here is an example.

```js
var svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var svg = document.querySelector('svg');
var rect;
var x,y;
var width;
var height;

svg.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    x = e.clientX;
    y = e.clientY;
    
    if(!rect){
        rect = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#f00');
        document.getElementById('svgOne').appendChild(rect);
    }
}, false);

svg.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    width = e.clientX - x;
    height = e.clientY - y;
    if(rect){
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', x);
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', y);
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', height);
        rect.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', width);
    }
}, false);
```

```html
<svg id="svgOne" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="578" height="200"> 
</svg>
```